# Get dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to select the dynamically added html element. However im able to bind event to dynamically created element

**Edit**

```
#idOfElement is select list
$(document).on('change', '#idOfElement', function () {
 // its running okay
});

// but i want to select it without any event link
```

// i know it will not work .. is there any way 
    var element= $('#idOfElement') ;// not working on dynamically added element

Comment: How can you select an element if it is not exist (at the moment)??

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 is there any way

Comment: There is no way without binding the document or a speciic element to watch for changes.

Comment: @SizS - No. It doesn't even make sense to select nothing. The only thing you can do is wait till you add the element, then select it.

Answer (score 2):

You are binding the event to the `document` object, not the element. Your event handler is listening for *any* change event in the document and then testing to see if it came from an element that matched the selector. This means that you can bind the event handler without waiting for the element to exist.

If you want to select the element itself, then you **must** wait until it exists before trying to find it in the DOM.